# Ring of Lipschitz Integers 

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $L$ be the ring of Lipschitz Integers and $a, b, c, d\in L$. Considere $L$ as a left $L$-module and let  $(a), (b), (c), (d)$ be the left submodules generated by $a, b, c,$ and $d$, respectively. It is true that the factor modules

$$\frac{L}{(c)+(d)}\;\;and\;\;\frac{(a)+(b)}{(ca)+(db)},$$

are isomorphic?

Comment: For those who don't know: a Lipschitz integer is a quaternion with integer coefficients.

Comment: Are b and c allowed to be units?

Comment: It is easy to prove that  $\frac{L}{(a)}\cong\frac{(c)}{(ac)}$, for $a, c\neq 0$, and  the question is a generalization of this fact. If $a$ or $c$ are units this fact is trivial. So, assume, in the question, that $a, b, c, d$ are not units. 

Comment: If both $b$ and $c$ are units, then you're asking if $L/L$ and $L/(a) + (d)$ are isomorphic. Or if you don't want to use units, take $a=d$, $b=c$, and $a, b$ coprime.

Comment: Thank you Zack for  your comments. The condiction $a$ and $b$ coprime is not well-defined in $L$ since $L$ is not a principal domain. But now I  think the answer to the question is NO. 
 Now I'm trying to prove that 

$$\frac{L}{(\bar{a})+(\bar{b})}\cong\frac{ (a) +(b)}{(\bar{a}a)+(\bar{b}b)}$$